# Twython - Saving Tweet IDs in a Text File

Tags: python, variables, twitter, save, twython

I am fairly new to Python, but have been enjoying it so far. I've been trying to write a code using Twython that saves the Tweet IDs of all the tweets that match my search query as variables in a file.

I find that I can print all of the IDs that pertain to my search query with the following code:

```
import sys
from twython import Twython

APP_KEY='XXXXXXXX'
APP_SECRET='XXXXXXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN='XXXXXXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET='XXXXXXXX'

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

I = 12345678910

result = twitter.search(q='WhateverImLooking4', since_id=str(I), count=100)


for item in result['statuses']:
       print(item['id_str'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Now, when I change the last two lines to this instead:

```
for item in result['statuses']:    
    f = open('Results.txt','w')
    f.write(item['id_str'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    f.close()
```

It will save only the smallest ID number to a text file. I'd like to be able to save all the results to a file AND ideally as variables ready to be used in another python code.

Hopefully this all makes sense!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are opening the file and writing over the previous ID each time you execute your for loop.

Try opening the file before the for loop:

```
f = open('Results.txt','w')
for item in result['statuses']:    
    f.write(item['id_str'].encode('ascii', 'ignore') + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Awesome! - one step closer! Why does that give all the results instead of my original code? Also, the results are given as one long continuous string - is there a way to spread them out into separate variables?  Thanks so much btw!

Comment: In your original code you were opening and closing the file each iteration of the loop.  When you open the file in the loop you would always start on the first line of the file and paste your data in over your previous data.  To add variables on a new line you can add "\n" to create a new line.  When you are reading the file in you can do something among the lines of "for line in file:  var = line"

Comment: Thanks! The issue is resolved! Many blessings upon the house of Matt Salzman!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Matt Salzman, the answer has been achieved.

```
f = open('Results.py', 'w')
i = 1
for item in result['statuses']: 
    f.write("x" + str(i) + " = " + item['id_str'].encode('ascii', 'ignore') + "\n")
    i = i + 1
f.close()
```

This opens the file before the loop which prevents each result from over-writing the other & the "\n" breaks up the results on a line by line basis. The variable "i" is used to achieve different variables every time the loop is ran for each result (i.e. x1, x2, x3... xn).

Thanks!